# Android resource linking failed - unexpected element

Tags: xml, manifest

I am running these errors:

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\jaxon\AndroidStudioProjects\lab6\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:29: error: unexpected element <uses-feature> found in <manifest><application>.
C:\Users\jaxon\AndroidStudioProjects\lab6\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:32: error: unexpected element <uses-feature> found in <manifest><application>.
C:\Users\jaxon\AndroidStudioProjects\lab6\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:36: error: unexpected element <intent-filter> found in <manifest><application>.
```

As someone who is new to application development, it is unclear to me what the issue is here, something is wrong with the manifest and I cannot figure this out, any ideas?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingLeanbackLauncher">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Lab6"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"
            tools:ignore="ManifestOrder,WrongManifestParent" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="true"
            tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </application>

</manifest>
```